# golang read log file contents inside a directory

Tags: go

i'm trying to read all log files inside a directory, Below code is able to read the filename but not its contents.

console output

```
ds-api-doc-.log false
2023/03/21 11:27:11 open /Users/xxx/ds-api-doc.log: no such file or directory 







 files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("./logs/")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(totalTicks)
            for _, file := range files {
                fmt.Println(file.Name(), file.IsDir())
                abs, err := filepath.Abs(file.Name())
        
                file, err := os.Open(abs)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                defer file.Close()
        
                scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
                for scanner.Scan() {
                    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
                }
        
                if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
        
            }
```

Comment: Check the permissions.

Comment: all files having -rw-r--r--

Comment: The filename is `ds-api-doc-.log` (not the trailing - before the extension) while the file not found has the name `ds-api-doc.log`. Use fmt.Printf with %q to see all characters in the filename. Show the value of abs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file.Name()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#FileInfo.Name) returns only the base name of the file.

[`filepath.Abs()`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath@go1.20.2#Abs) will join the given path, in this case the file's base name, to the current working directory. Therefore the returned `abs` value will be missing the `./logs/` segment of the file's path.

To fix that you can do the following:

```golang
abs, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Join("logs", file.Name()))
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`filepath.WalkDir`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath@go1.20.2#WalkDir), which provides the file's path to the `fn` argument.

```golang
err := filepath.WalkDir("./logs/", func(path string, de fs.DirEntry, err error) error) {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    } else if de.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    // ...
    return nil
})
```